# How do I stop git from adding carriage returns when cloneing a repo onto windows?

Tags: git, git-config

I still have XP on my laptop and have installed Git so that I can do some work on it. When I clone a repository from my server (which is linux) it automatically adds carriage returns onto each line. So now Git thinks that every file has been modified when, in fact, they haven't.

I've tried adding the following lines to my .gitconfig file to no avail

```
[core]
    autocrlf = true
```

or

```
[core]
    autocrlf = input
```

I have also tried running

```
git config core.autocrlf <value>
```

within the repository in question, and then reset hard to head. This also didn't seem to work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not "autocrlf = false?".

Comment: well... that would have been the obvious thing to do now, wouldn't it? It works now. Thanks for fielding my stupid question.

Comment: Is there a way to specify this when cloning the repository on Windows? I have a Linux based repository, that I'm cloning down on Windows to then ship to a remote Linux box. I'd use the "download zip" option, but there's lots of submodules that would keep me from using that as a workaround